# Angular 5 with Firebase Collections Routing

Tags: angular

How does it work? It just keeps showing as null? I need to route the category page to the product page based on the name of the product

This is the ts:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class CategoriesComponent {

      ngOninit() {
      this.route$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: 
      Params) => {
      if (params) {
      console.log(params['collection']);
      } else {
      console.log(params['items']);
      }
      });
```

This is the database structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else needs the answer, this worked for me:

```
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('this routes to =>', data, name);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much information on the structure and naming of your Firestore database; however, give this a shot:

```
constructor(
  public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  db: AngularFirestore,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private productsService: ProductsService,
  private afs: AngularFirestore
) {
  this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously();
  this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.name = params.get('id')
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.itemCollection = this.afs.collection<Item>('items', ref => {
    return ref.where('name', '==', this.name);
  });
  this.items = this.itemCollection.valueChanges();
  this.items.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

The difference here is that I first allowed the constructor to subscribe to your route params and retrieve the name from the address bar.

---

## Solution

Because you have the parameter named `:id` in your router module, you'll need to retrieve the parameter value with this same identifier.

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  this.name = params.get('id')
});
```

Once you've retrieved this route parameter, request the matching documents from Firestore using the query operators:

```
this.itemCollection = this.afs.collection<Item>('items', ref => {
  return ref.where('name', '==', this.name);
});
```

Comment: Oops! I was passing `name` to the `ref.where()` method instead of `this.name`.  It works now. Please remove the previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should subscribe to your URL params in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params['collection']);
    console.log(params['items']);.
  });
}
```

Comment: I get 'undefined' for both.

Comment: what is your URL look like ?